# How to place a PERPETUAL futures market order using python-binance:

Tags: python, api, binance

`client.futures_create_order(symbol=sym, side='BUY', type='MARKET', quantity=0.001)`

When I use this, the order is BTCUSDT_0326. (Not perpetual futures)

How about BTCUSD Perpetual Futures?

Comment: It's clear exactly what you need. Please consider editing your question and add more details